# Getting 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records' error with Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

I upgraded from one version of Amazon MWS (marketplace web service) version

```
        https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01
```

to

```
        https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01
```

and started getting the following error:

> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

The keys are all correct and double checked.

Answer (score 6):

Someone at Amazon decided to change the order of parameters for some reason...

```
IMarketplaceWebServiceOrders service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient(

                applicationName, 
                applicationVersion, 
                accessKeyId, 
                secretAccessKey, 
                config);
```

to

```
MarketplaceWebServiceOrders service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient(

                accessKeyId, 
                secretAccessKey, 
                applicationName, 
                applicationVersion, 
                config);
```

So obviously it compiles but fails.

Just switch them and it will work. Hopefully they didn't switch anything else important like this in the API.

Comment: Yep, this is also the case for the Subscriptions API. Another inconsistency with MWS smh.