# Amazon MWS client library C# AWS Access Key Id error

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon C# client library to get product information and keep getting an error " The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." (Yes, I tried the seller forum, but didn't get an answer there). When I use the same Access Key using their scratchpad, I get the correct response. I did see this post ([Getting 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records' error with Amazon MWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278327/getting-the-aws-access-key-id-you-provided-does-not-exist-in-our-records-error)) and tried swapping the parameters and that didn't work. Here is my C# code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
string AccessKey = "xxx";
            string SecretKey = "xxx";
            string AppName = "ProductFunctionsApp";
            string AppVersion = "1.0";
            string ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
            string SellerId="xxxx";
            string MarketPlaceId = "xxx";//US
            //right now MWSAuthToken is only if a developer is using a sellers account
              MarketplaceWebServiceProductsConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsConfig();
             config.ServiceURL = ServiceURL;
             config.SignatureMethod = "HmacSHA256";
             config.SignatureVersion = "2";
 MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient client = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient(AppName, AccessKey, SecretKey, AppVersion, config);
  ASINListType type = new ASINListType();
            List<string> ASINList = new List<string>();
            ASINList.Add("B001E6C08E");
            type.ASIN = ASINList;
           ;
          GetCompetitivePricingForASINRequest request = new GetCompetitivePricingForASINRequest();
            request.SellerId = SellerId;
            request.ASINList = type;
            request.MarketplaceId = MarketPlaceId;
  GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse response = client.GetCompetitivePricingForASIN(request);
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the PHP pack. Any news on this?

Comment: Okay, never mind, solved it: I defined constants in the middle of my script and they ended up being empty; PHP basics -.- I found this dumping the parameters of the constructor of MarketplaceWebService_Client

Answer (score 0):

Some of their API Clients have the class initialization parameters defined in different orders.

So if you copy and paste the initialization code you'll end up with the application name being sent instead of the access key.

```
        var service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient(
            applicationName, applicationVersion, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, config);
```

And it's different here:

```
        var service = new FBAInventoryServiceMWSClient(
            accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, applicationName, applicationVersion, config);
```

Just check each one carefully.